# Drop down animation of a view from tool bar in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

[image: iOS App Screenshot]

In my app I have a tool bar on top. There are four buttons in this tool bar. I want to have an animation so that on touching one button a view will come down where I want to have a switch.

I just want to implement the animation like "Bookmark Added" in the below image. How can i implement this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use this code snippet (Make appropriate changes) which will work for you):

[View Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH6-SW1)

```
CGRect frame = YourView.frame;
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];

frame.origin.x = 0; // 
pushView.frame = frame;
self.YourView.frame = CGRectMake(250, 45, 500, 960);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```